Need Assistance with STL File Uploads in Shopware 6 Shopping Cart
I am looking for a solution to a problem I have. In Shopware 6, I want the customer to be able to upload STL files in the shopping cart, possibly for each product. I haven’t found a suitable plugin so far.
Thanks in advance for the help!
I am unable to find a suitable plugin, so I am looking for an alternative solution to this problem.

Have your experience on writing your own Shopware plugins?
